# At what height will the mass fall off the loop de loop?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, energy

I have been having trouble with the following problem that my teacher posed to us today:

A mass starts at rest at the top of a
frictionless ramp, 2R, above the ground. It then
slides down the ramp and enters into a frictionless,
vertical loop with radius, R. How high will the
mass get before it falls off the loop?

He provided us with the work to solve the problem (and a slightly lacking explanation for his steps). I understand everything EXCEPT the first step, where he equates Fc=mgcos ($\theta$). Where did the cos($\theta$) part come from? Doesn't gravity act directly downwards?

Please see work I copied below. Thanks!
[image: Work for the Loop de Loop Problem]

Comment: Where is angle theta on your drawings?

Comment: It is not given. From what I see in the work, the teacher expressed theta in terms of the height and radius of the loop (according to the second drawing on the page).

Comment: The centripetal force $f=m\ v^2/r$ is only valid when $f$ is the radial force, which is where the $cos \theta$ comes from.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. It breaks search functionality, and it doesn't work for blind users. I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. In the future, please add this tag to this type of problem. Please don't cut and paste on the internet without crediting the author. It's rude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the centripetal force, that is, the force in the radial direction that is necessary to support a circular motion has two contributions, the normal force from the loop and the component of gravity in the radial direction.

Answer (score -1):

> I understand everything EXCEPT the first step, where he equates Fg=mgcos (θ).

He doesn't equate $F_g=mg\cos\theta$ as far as I can tell. Maybe you meant $F_c$ or $F_r$? Your notes indicate that the force component directed toward the center has not only a normal force due to contact with the track but also a component of weight. If you take the weight force, $mg$ *down* and break it into radial and tangential components at the position indicated ($\theta$ from the top), then the radial component is $mg\cos\theta$ *inward*  and the tangential is $mg\sin\theta$ *backward* (thus slowing down the object).
So the total radial force is: $$F_r=F_N+mg\cos\theta.$$

If the object loses contact with the track, the normal force is zero, and the only radial force is $mg\cos\theta$. That must equal the mass times the centripetal acceleration:
$$mg\cos\theta = ma_c=m \frac{v^2}{R}$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Yes, sorry, I meant Fc. I hadn't thought of gravity in terms of radial/tangential before since I am used to vertical/horizontal.

Comment: Down-voter, please explain what is not useful about the answer.